# Snap.svg changing colour attr

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying to learn how to use snap.svg and I am currently trying to change the colour of a part of my svg. However everytime I try this the page goes blank and i get the error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of null)
This is my

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="dist/snap.svg.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var s = Snap(800,600);
    var g = s.group();
    var cube = Snap.load("theCube2.0.svg", function ( f ) {

        var g = f.select("SVGID_2_");
        g.attr({fill: '#101010'});
        s.append( f );
    } );


</script>
```

I have also linked my svg.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/185556553/theCube2.0.svg

Comment: use `var g = f.select("#SVGID_2_");` i.e syntax is `f.selector("css selector")`

Comment: Ok thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to mention the css selector `#SVGID_2_` not `SVGID_2_`

Use

```
var g = f.select("#SVGID_2_");
```

syntax:

```
f.selector("css selector")
```